# Bootstrap's Footer doesn't displays correctly when keyboard shows up on tablets

Tags: android, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, keyboard

I have a site specifically made for tablets with Bootstrap 3.0.2 and what I am trying to do is a footer which displays itself only when the keyboard is up on the screen, the purpose is to add some functions to the keyboard, like certain iPad apps does.

Now, I'm ok with everything that concerns: telling tablet browsers from other browsers, detecting when the keyboard is displayed.

My only problem is that I can't make the footer stay where it has to stay.

This is the code used to display the navbar, it behaves correctly when the keyboard is not shown.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    Something
</nav>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! 
This is a working solution:

```
function changeFooterPosition() {   
  $('.footer-menu').css('top', window.innerHeight + window.scrollY - 30 + "px");
}

$(document).bind('scroll', function() {
  changeFooterPosition();
});
```

Of course you have to replace "footer-menu" with  your footer-element class and "30" with it's height.

The only problem is that the footer wait for the end of the scroll to move.